# .How can I spread my text over multiple jtextpanes?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I´m building a simple word-editor in java. Currently, everything´s working fine. Now I want to create "Pages", like in word. The JTextPane representing a Page is supposed to check if it´s full and then create a new JTextpane under it. With a scrollbar I would be able to scroll between them. So far this wouldn't be problematic. However, all the pages should belong to a single document, and if I were to delete a line on let´s say page 2, every line on every other page will be moved up. (For example) Is there an easy way to do this, or will I have to create DocumentListeners for each JTextPane, changing everything on each change? Also, is there a way to extend selections over multiple pages?

Personally I havn't tried anything as of yet, since I want some tips before writing myself into a corner. I thought that I could make the pages uneditable, and instead use a caretListener to check the position the user clicks on, to edit an invisible infinite JTextPane containing the actual document, which would write it´s content to the visible pages.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of unknowns, but maybe the following will give you something to think about.

> all the pages should belong to a single document,

Agreed.

> The JTextPane representing a Page is supposed to check if it´s full and then create a new JTextpane under it

Maybe add each text pane to a JScrollPane, but don't display the scrollbars or Border of the scroll pane.

> if I were to delete a line on let´s say page 2, every line on every other page will be moved up

You would need to manually control the viewport of each scroll pane. The first page would position the viewport at offset 0. The next page would position the viewport at the offset that represents your page height.

Then any changes to the Document should be automatically reflected in all the text panes.

You would also probably need to use `setAutoScrolls(false)` to prevent the viewport from scrolling as you drag the mouse.

> is there a way to extend selections over multiple pages?

Selection is a property of the text pane, not the Document.

Not sure what will happen as you try to drag the mouse from one text pane to another.

I'm guessing you might need some special logic. Maybe using mouseEntered/Exited events to trigger this type of processing.

Comment: after reading the question I made a rough test, which is very similar to the solution you describe. "The next page would position the viewport at the offset that represents your page height" represents another challenge:  how to divide the  content so it is looks nice (for example avoiding half lines show at the page top or bottom).

Comment: @c0der, I suggested there would be lots of unknowns. Regarding the half lines, you could use  the `viewToModel(...)` method to get an offset of the character at the beginning of the line based on the (suggested) height. Then you would use the modelToView(...) method to get the real rectangle represented by that character and adjust the height so is completely displays the character.